# Regex Negative Lookbehind Matches Lookbehind text .NET

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Say I have the following strings:

```
PB-GD2185-11652-MTCH
GD2185-11652-MTCH
KD-GD2185-11652-MTCH
KD-GD2185-11652
```

I want REGEX.IsMatch to return true if the string has MTCH in it and does not start with PB.

I expected the regex to be the following:

```
^(?<!PB)\S+(?=MTCH)
```

but that gives me the following matches:

```
PB-GD2185-11652-
GD2185-11652-
KD-GD2185-11652-
```

I do not understand why the negative lookbehind not only doesn't exclude the match but includes the PB characters in the match. The positive lookahead works as expected.

**EDIT 1**

Let me start with a simpler example. The following regex matches all of the strings as I would expect it to:

```
\S+
```

The following regex still matches all of the strings even though I would expect it not to:

```
\S+(?!MTCH)
```

The following regex matches all but the final H character on the first three strings:

```
\S+(?<!MTCH)
```

From the documentation at regex 101, a lookahead looks for text to the right of the pattern and a lookbehind looks for text to the left of the pattern, so having a lookahead at the beginning of a string does not jive with the documentation.

**Edit 2**

take another example with the following three strings:

```
grey
greyhound
hound
```

the regex:

```
 ^(?<!grey)hound
```

only matches the final hound. whereas the regex:

```
^(?<!grey)\S+
```

matches all three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the greediness of \S+. When dealing with lookarounds and greedy quantifiers you can easily match more characters than you expect. One way to deal with this is to insert a negative lookaround in a group with the greedy quantifier to exclude it as a match as stated in this question:

> [How to non-greedy multiple lookbehind matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232220/how-to-non-greedy-multiple-lookbehind-matches)

and on this helpful website about greediness in regular expressions:

> http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

Note that this second link has a few other ways to deal with the greediness in various situations.

A good regular expression for this situation is as follows:

```
^(?<!PB)((?!PB)\S+)(MTCH)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a lookahead: `^(?!PB)\S+(?=MTCH)`. Using the look-behind means the `PB` has to come before the first character.

Comment: PB does have to come before the first character, in other words it is always the start of the string

Comment: I'm actually getting the same result with the lookahead.

Comment: `var result = new Regex(@"(?!PB)^\S+(?=MTCH)").IsMatch("PB-GD2185-11652-MTCH");` `result` is `false`.

Comment: It totally matches in regex101 :/

Comment: this works correctly in the code but does not work correctly in any of the regex designers I tried it in.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this it is going to be much clearer to do it logically within the code. So first check if the string matches `MTCH` and then that it doesn't match `^PB`