# Matching object construction in source files using regex

Tags: regex

I am decent with regex patterns. But today I stumbled up on trying to create a pattern to match object construction like `"new Class(..)"` in typical C++ source files. Unfortunately, the `new` operator in C++ has multiple usages. For example, I am trying to match it in the following text

```
// This is the new connection object which does xyz and abc
 Connection = new (xbt->length 
                     + sizeof(PVOID))
                  CCONECTION("ipaddress");
```

Regex Pattern tried:
`(?<=new)(?s).*?CCONECTION`

The above pattern does not match

```
new (xbt->length 
^^^   
      + sizeof(PVOID))
       CCONECTION("ipaddress");
              ^^^
```

Instead it matches

```
    new connection object which does xyz and abc
    ^^^
 Connection = new (xbt->length 
                     + sizeof(PVOID))
                  CCONECTION("ipaddress");
                         ^^^
```

Is there a way I can lookbehind greedily only to the nearest "new" word before the CCONECTION? I tried multiple look behind options but unable to get it working.

I am using ripgrep with its multiline support(-U) to match the above regex as 
`rg -U "(?<=new)(?s).*?CCONECTION" --pcre2 -g a.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232220/how-to-non-greedy-multiple-lookbehind-matches

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped in rethinking what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a negative look ahead to ensure `new` does not appear in the intended captured match. You should use this regex,

```
(?<=new)(?s)(?!.*new).*?CCONECTION
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6In2ug/1)**

Comment: Glad I could help :)