# regex match whole joined string

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to write a function that will return the whole section of 'conjoined string'.
The only break should be the start or end of the string and a space character

1. I would like to match a section of "touching" sting.
2. If it contains a matching regex, return the "touching" part
3. Else return false

   ```
   function function_a(string, regex) {
       try {
       const reg = new RegExp(/(?:^|\s)/.source + '(' + /.*?/.source + regex.source + /.*?/.source + ')' + /(?:\s|$)/.source, regex.flags)
       const match = string.match(reg)
       if (match) {
           return match[1]
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
       return false;
   } }
   ```

The tests I have are

```
describe('function_a', () => {
    it('should return awordplease', () => {
        const xyz = "mister potter, awordplease";
        expect(function_a(xyz, /(word)/)).toEqual('awordplease');
    });

    it('should return a-man-witha', () => {
        const xyz = "a-man-witha wierd way of sayingit";
        expect(function_a(xyz, /(man|wierd|people)/)).toEqual('a-man-witha');
    });

    it('should return wierd', () => {
        const xyz = "a-man-witha wierd way of sayingit";
        expect(function_a(xyz, /(lady|wierd|people)/)).toEqual('wierd');
    });

    it('should return 3434this__432eed2e-tro_py', () => {
        const xyz = "skdjmdkas 3434this__432eed2e-tro_py wdsds asjbchjzxacuyvdkajsnfrsd";
        expect(function_a(xyz, /(this|that)/)).toEqual('3434this__432eed2e-tro_py');
    });

it('should return skdjmdkas3434select__432eed2e-tro_py', () => {
    const xyz = "skdjmdkas3434select__432eed2e-tro_py";
    expect(function_a(xyz, /(select)/)).toEqual('skdjmdkas3434select__432eed2e-tro_py');
});
```

});

I can't quite get the regex to work out. I think the issue is with the (?:^|\s) at the start, it matches too much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How to non-greedy multiple lookbehind matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232220/how-to-non-greedy-multiple-lookbehind-matches)
I added a greedy non-capturing group before the match and a positive look behind,

```
.*(?<=\s|^)
```

so now the RegExp is built as follows

```
new RegExp(/(?:.*)(?<=\s|^)/.source + '(' + /.*?/.source + regex.source + /.*?/.source + ')' + /(?:\s|$)/.source, regex.flags)
```

Comment: Note `(?:.*)(?<=\s|^)` = `.*(?<=\s|^)` (shorter).